# Getting int from a user to array in c

Tags: c

I'm trying to get an array of ints from the user, i did check for illegal input and it works just fine except for the last input:

```
int *array=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*size);
```

For example for the size 3, let's say the input is 3  5  2.2

So when i assign the numbers into the array the last input (2.2) is considered as 2 and the program continues even though it shouldn't.

Any ideas?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you show the code that processes the input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has nothing to do with your use of `malloc()`. Instead, you need to check how you are parsing the input.  A very naive parser would just read the `2.2` as `2` with some extra garbage at the end.  [`scanf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) for example, behaves this way.

You can test this easily:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(void) {
  int i;
  scanf("%d",&i);
  printf("%d\n",i);
}
```

Feed it a decimal, such as `4.2` and what do you get?  `4` -- what happened to the `.2` at the end?  It's still in the input buffer, actually, waiting for something to read it.

You will have to use a smarter scanner to verify that the user isn't entering garbage.

Comment: I guessed so, because i was able to see that .2 ("garbage") went into the next scan. I guess my question is: how do i prevent it from happening while still using scanf?

Comment: If your data has floats, use floats.

Answer (score 0):

As **PaulProgrammer** suggested above that you will have to use a smarter `scanner` to verify that the user isn't entering garbage.You can use `character reader` scanner and then check if value entered by user is an `integer` or not by checking some characteristics, if it belongs to `int` just convert the character string into `integer` using functions like `atoi()`, else output a warning to user.

I have written a small code for you which takes 6 integers and checks for floats and other wrong values.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 int main()
 {
    char ch,arr[20]; //arr is an array for storing the character values initially taken as input.

    int x,input[100],i=0,count=0; //input is an array which will hold the integer values

    while((x=scanf("%c",&ch))>0){
        if(ch=='.')       //checking if there is any floating point number
        {
            printf("Wrong Input");
            return 0;
        }

        if(ch>='0' && ch <='9')       //check if ch is in the range of 0-9
        {
           arr[i++]=ch;
        }

        if(ch==' ' || ch=='\n'){
            arr[i]='\0';
            input[count++]=atoi(arr);
            i=0;
        }
        if(count==7) break;
    }

    for(int loop=0;loop<6;loop++){
        printf("%d ",input[loop]);
    }
}
```

I hope you got the point.Please notice when you write this code make sure that it checks for every possible input error.